# Link tags in template file auto closing.

Tags: theming, navigation

I’m having an issue wrapping a link around some output in a template file.   I have the right template file; and I can put text like ‘start here’ and ‘end here’  and it prints out where I want the ‘a href’ tag to start and end.

However when I put in the starting ‘a href’ it auto closes.   I can put in a ‘div’ and that doesn’t auto close.   I’ve tried 
`<div href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.location.assign("'.$link.'")” >`  and although that html output looks right it doesn’t work either.

I’ve also used at ‘function l’ but can’t pass the $content in.

Any ideas how I can either stop the auto close, get the javascript to work or a function I can use to output the link but will except the content being passed in.

Here's my code

```
print '<a href="'.$link.'" >'; 
     print $field->content;
     print '</a>';
```

Comment: Can you mention the exact requirement because you can not write "href" attribute in <div> its for <a>.

Comment: I'm trying to make a whole div clickable .

Comment: If you wants whole <div> clickable. Instated of putting a "div" as wrapper you can write a css for your <a> tag. It will works as <div>. just put a class and set the css property as display:block.

Comment: the 'a tag' auto closes, I don't know why it does this.  .  Otherwise the code would work fine.   so output is 

<a href="mylink.html"></a>
my content
</a>

Comment: Does the content that you are wrapping have an anchor tag inside it? This could be a hidden anchor that you will only see when inspecting source. I'm asking because you cant nest anchors.

Comment: You will need to sanitize the $link variable if it's coming from a source you can't trust. A user can be a victim of XSS (cross site scripting). Check out [D7 handling text in a secure fashion](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/security/writing-secure-code/handle-text-in-a-secure-fashion#s-in-practice]

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that there where links in the content being outputted.  Once I changed that the links stopped auto closing.

Answer (score 0):

Use [filter_xss](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/filter_xss/7.x) on `$field->content`. You can filter out the anchor tags this way.